# text leak out from one div to another

Tags: html, css

i have 2 div separate, each one of them have the same "container" class and his own id. each div contains text - when i ran the file on my computer its work fine. but when i open the file via my iPhone the text from the upper div leak inside the bottom div. I'm afraid this will happened in another devices. 
here is my code:

```
    <div id="about_us" class="container">
<h1>texttexttexttexttexttexttext</h1>
<p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
<p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
</div>

<div id="our_services" class="container">
<h1>text1</h1>
</div>

.container{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
}
#about_us{
text-align: center;
height: 250px;
font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular",arial,"Times New Roman";
color:gray;
}

#about_us p{
width: 55%;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
direction: rtl;
padding-bottom: 10px;
line-height: 30px;
}
#our_services{
height: 450px;
text-align: center;
font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular",arial,"Times New Roman";
color: black;
background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
}
```

anyone know how to fix this?
thanks!

Comment: Don't set `heght` to the text blocks.

Comment: Maybe give css prop. word-break a shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the overflow property, here is an example of using: `overflow: auto;` -- this will turn the div into a scroll-able container once the text becomes larger than the fixed height:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrus8oo1/

Some more reading on overflow here: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

OR -

You can change the `height: 500px;` in .container to: `min-height: 500px;`
Setting a minimum height will allow the container to grow with the text so it doesn't spill out.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrus8oo1/1/